# Pass class instance to all views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have an Asp.Net MVC application using domain authentication, the _Layout.cshtml file contains a call to `User.Identity.Name` which on the domain environment returns the correct domain username.

I have a `Person` model that stores that individuals details.

In the Home Controller I instance the class and pass it into my view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var personInstance = new Person((User.Identity.Name));
    return View(personInstance);
}
```

Then in my _Layout.cshtml I add the model I'm using:

```
@model namespace.Models.Person
```

Then from there I replace `User.Identity.Name` with the required property

```
<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @Model.fullName</p>
 @*<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name</p>*@
```

This works fine for the Home Views but if I access another view that is already using another model it throws an exception:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[namespace.Models.Logging]', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'namespace.Models.Person'.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: You can't have two models in the same view.  If you add a `Person` model in the template `_Layout.cshtml` you cant add any model in the views that use this template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the View Model to expose a `Person` property and then create an instance of this, populating it in a similar manner and pass it into your view.

```
var model = new MyModel();
model.Person = new Person((User.Identity.Name));
return View(model);
```